# Smartest way to extract a string number and convert in to int

Tags: php

I need to create a function which will be able to extract string representations of numbers and return them as integers but I'm unsure about the most efficient way to do this.

I was thinking that I could possibly have a dictionary of numbers and look for matches in the string.

Or I could trim away anything that came before the word "third" and after the word "ninth" and process the results.

**string**

```
"What is the third, fifth, sixth and ninth characters to question A"
```

**desired output**

```
array(3,5,6,9);
```

Comment: A dictionary is better, if you just trim, the solution will not be generic and will fail if you have any other word order.

Comment: here you go http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7082-PHP-Convert-a-string-of-English-words-to-numbers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this, complete work for you!

```
<?php

function get_numbers($s) {
    $str2num = array(
        'first' => 1,
        'second' => 2,
        'third' => 3,
        'fourth' => 4,
        'fifth' => 5,
        'sixth' => 6,
        'seventh' => 7,
        'eighth' => 8,
        'ninth' => 9,
    );
    $pattern = "/(".implode(array_keys($str2num), '|').")/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches);
    $ans = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $key) {
        array_push($ans, $str2num[$key]);
    }
    return $ans;
}

var_dump(get_numbers("What is the third, fifth, sixth and ninth characters to question A"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather ugly code (because of "global"), but simply working

```
$dict = array('third' => 3, 'fifth' => 5, 'sixth' => 6, 'ninth' => 9);
$string = 'What is the third, fifth, sixth and ninth characters to question A';
$output = null;

if (preg_match_all('/(' . implode('|', array_keys($dict)) . ')/', $string, $output))
    $output = array_map(function ($in) { global $dict; return $dict[$in]; }, $output[1]);

print_r($output);
```

**Update**

The exact code without use of "global":

```
$dict = array('third' => 3, 'fifth' => 5, 'sixth' => 6, 'ninth' => 9);
$string = 'What is the third, fifth, sixth and ninth characters to question A';
$output = null;

if (preg_match_all('/(' . implode('|', array_keys($dict)) . ')/', $string, $output))
    $output = array_map(function ($in) use ($dict) { return $dict[$in]; }, $output[1]);

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Best answer, I should use array_map more.

Comment: just tested it, I get the following output `Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "What is the first, third, first, first, third, sixth and ninth characters to question A";
$numbers = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3); //...

preg_match_all("(".implode('|',array_keys($numbers)).")", $string, $matches );

$result = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $match){
    $result[] = $numbers[$match];
}

var_dump($result);
```